# Telerik MVC Grid : How to refresh Grid after some updates ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have two grids:

- Animal
- Location.

`Location` has foreign key `AnimalId`. After I insert row in `Animal`, the dropdown list in the `Location` table is the old one - it isn't getting refreshed (it doesn't have the new animal). I tried calling `ajaxRequest()`, but nothing.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You need to show your markup for the Telerik grid as well as any scripts you may have that run as a result of inserting data/trying to refresh grid. Seeing that and your Action method in the controller will help so I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not working for me either.    I have a list of items bound to the grid.

I modified data and i'm calling the rebind() in javascript.
But it does nothing.

If I refresh the grid using the button it works or by refreshing the page.

Comment: Exactly my problem. Did you solve it somehow?

Comment: I haven't solved it.  I posted on Telerik forum too, no one is responding there.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var grid = $('#LocationGrid').data('tGrid');
grid.rebind();
```

It should work :)

Comment: I think it's not possible till now. But you can try to handle OnDataBound event and look for this column and try to change its data. Good luck :)